# [React-Admin]: Locale URL parameter

Tags: react-admin

How can I add locale URL param to the URL path using React-Admin?

E.g. `en/some-resource` should become `de/some-resource` on locale change. Also, navigating to `en/some-resource` should change the app locale to the one specified in the URL.

I've provided a custom history object that checks if the location includes locale parameter, but it all seems to be too hacky.